# How to access url of this endpoint @GetMapping("/catalog/**") inside its method?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, endpoint

I have following endpoint:

```
@GetMapping("/catalog/**")
public String getCatalog(final Model model){
    // code

}
```

This endpoint handles such urls: **catalog/clothes**, **catalog/clothes/men**,**catalog/clothes/women** and so on.
When I enter such url:

> http://localhost:8080/catalog/clothes/women

this endpoint gets fired.
I need to get this url inside the method. How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The 2nd snippet looks Ok and the problem it is not getting called seems to be in other code, or share the class/configuration code.

```
@Controller
public class CatalogController {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CatalogController.class);

    @GetMapping("/catalog/**")
    public String getCatalog(final Model model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
        logger.debug(request.getRequestURL().toString());
        logger.debug(request.getQueryString());
        logger.debug("Inside catalog");
        return null;
    }
}
```

If URL your enter is like - http://localhost:8080/catalog/a/b/c/d?key=value
The above code will log:

- http://localhost:8080/catalog/a/b/c/d (URL)
- key=value (query string)

http://localhost:8080/catalog/a/b/c/d